# Can't get class function to work with an IF statement in PHP

Tags: php, function

This function is part of a class. I get the "else" to work if its more than 6 char but the first echo keeps giving me

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"Name... "'
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)"

no matter what I do

```
public function showOutput(){
    if (strlen($this->name) < 6) { 
  echo " Name needs more than 5 characters ";
    } else  {
    echo "Name " . $this->name;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT** I copied the code from one editor to notepadd++ and for some reason it cashed a " ' " on the line. It bothered me for an hour and a half hence signing up and asking. Thank you and sorry for the trouble. I did read the duplicate answers but none helped hence why I asked.

Thank you

Comment: you need to end lines with a semi-colon..

Comment: you miss ";" (semicolon) in echo " Name needs more than 5 characters "

Comment: Its there and i still get the same error

Comment: Are you sure that $this->name is accessible within the context of this function? Try var_dump($this->name) it just to see the function can access it.

Comment: If the semicolon is in your code, then please edit your question to include it.  The code that you have posted will not run and will return an error just like the one you describe because `echo " Name needs more than 5 characters "` needs to have a semicolon at the end.